# Neo4j and apoc procedure

Tags: neo4j, compilation

At my organization IT will not permit me to download the apoc jar library. My next option is to download the source and compile. However the rub in that is that Gradle is not an approved tool nor do I have Internet access.

Is there a manual process for me to compile the source using Java? What are the other dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like https://travis-ci.org for your own build. APOC uses https://travis-ci.org/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures for automating tests after a git push (or for testing PRs).

In the same way you should be able to run travis on your own, maybe on a forked version of apoc that uses `gradle shadowJar`. Additionally you need to tweak travis config to deploy your artifact to an approriate location - see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/ for details.

On a different notice: If my organization would not permit me to download jar artifacts, nor provide internet access to run builds, my immediate next action would be updating mv CV - just sayin'.